# Unable to import faker locale sub package in React app (react-scripts v4)

Tags: reactjs, webpack-4, faker.js

According to [`faker` docs](https://fakerjs.dev/guide/localization.html#individual-localized-packages), it is encouraged to import individual locales using the following syntax (to avoid loading full 5Mb faker bundle):

```
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker/locale/de';
```

However, after running `yarn add @faker-js/faker`, the app won't build and I get this error:

```bash
Module not found: Can't resolve '@faker-js/faker/locale/de' in (...)
```

It works fine if I do

```
import { fakerDE } from '@faker-js/faker';
```

However, I lose the benefit of a [reduced bundle size](https://fakerjs.dev/guide/localization.html#individual-localized-packages).

It seems like this is due to the way `exports` are configured in faker's `package.json`. They are [not supported in webpack 4](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/9509#issuecomment-1381896299), however, in order to upgrade to webpack 5, I would also need to migrate my entire React app to react-scripts v5, which contains a lot of breaking changes.

So, is there an alternate way of importing individual locales, while keeping the faker bundle size down and without upgrading react-scripts ?